# How are "$f$ integrable" and "$\vert f \vert$ integrable" related?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

Here is the question I'm asking myself:

> If $\vert f \vert$ is Lebesgue-integrable, is $f$ Lebesgue-integrable?

I'm taking an undergraduate class, covering integration by Stone. The reverse statement was proven, but I'm having issues coming up with an idea for a proof or counter-example of this.

Comment: What is your definition of "integratable" ? (integrable ?)

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I meant integrable, sorry.

Comment: If $f$ is already known to be Lebesgue measurable, then the answer is yes.

Comment: It depends on the integral you are working with (Riemann, Lebesgue. Gauge-integral). In the case of Lebesgue, $f$ is integrable iff $|f|$ is integrable.

Comment: @OliverDiaz That is not correct. See my answer for a counter example.

Comment: @JustANoob: In the context of your example, you are right. I presume that when a function is to go through the grinder of (Lesguesue) integrability, is already at least measurable.

Comment: @OliverDiaz  Actually that statement fails for each of those three integrals. (i) $f$ Riemann integrable implies $|f|$ integrable, but not conversely. (ii) ditto for the Lebesgue integral.  (iii) for the Henstock-Kurzweil integral $f$ integrable does *not* imply $|f|$ is integrable, nor conversely.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson: As in my comment, when one talks about Lebesgue measurability of a function, I always presume that it is at least measurable. Under this proviso, $f$ is Lebesgue integrable iff $|f|$ is Lebesgue integrable. As for the other types of integrals, one may obtained all kinds of counter examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick any set $E \subset (0,1)$ that is not measurable. Consider the function
$$f(x) = I_E(x)  - I_{((0,1)-E)}(x)$$

Since $f^{-1}(\{1\}) = E$, $f$ is not measurable, hence not integrable. But $g(x) = |f(x)| = 1$ for all $x$, hence measurable. Since $\int |f| d \lambda = 1$, $|f|$ is integrable.

Comment: What does your notation $I_E(x)$ mean?

Comment: @RonLauterbach $I_E(x) = 1$ if $x \in E$, else 0.

Comment: @JustANoob:  $f$ is Lebesgue integrable iff $f$ is measurable and $|f|$ is Lebesgue intgrable.